# WCF POST method get error 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, wcf

I am using WCF POST method, once i added parameter POST to the service its return error 400 Bad Request, if i left the parameter empty it can access to my service.

This is my Interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.IO;
namespace SampleArticle
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IRestService" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract(Namespace="IRestService/JSONData")]
    public interface IRestService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,UriTemplate = "authorize")]
        Stream authorize(Stream streamdata);

    }
}
```

This is my Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>

    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>


    <services>
      <service name="SampleArticle.RestService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SampleArticle.IRestService" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>        
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>


    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>


 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
   <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />

  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Im using Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP to POST

```
Dim objXmlHttpMain , URL

URL="http://localhost/SampleArticle/RestService.svc/authorize" 

strJSONToSend = "{""acctId"": ""Test10001"","
strJSONToSend = strJSONToSend & """language"": 200,"
strJSONToSend = strJSONToSend & """Code"": ""Test"","
strJSONToSend = strJSONToSend & """token"": ""abcd123412341234"","
strJSONToSend = strJSONToSend & """serialNo"": ""20161020160455982841""}"

// if i set the parameter to empty i can access to the service
'strJSONToSend  = ""
Set objXmlHttpMain = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
'on error resume next 
objXmlHttpMain.open "POST",URL, False 

// if i change the  "application/json" to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" it works 
'objXmlHttpMain.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
objXmlHttpMain.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

objXmlHttpMain.send strJSONToSend 


//check for output
S = objXmlHttpMain.responseText
response.write S

set objJSONDoc = nothing 
set objResult = nothing
```

Server log msg

> Incoming message for operation 'authorize' (contract 'IRestService' with namespace 'IRestService/JSONData') contains an unrecognized http body format value 'Json'. The expected body format value is 'Raw'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.

if i change the Content-Type "application/json" to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
it works , but i need the data in JSON format.
Is there any setting i am missing with ? Please advice.

Comment: You are probably making bad request :) - you really should show how you call the service too. See [MCVE] for guidance on posting code.

Comment: Are you sure `strJSONToSend` have correct JSON format ?

Comment: i guess so... any suggestion ?

Comment: Yes your JSON is correct and is : `{"acctId": "Test10001","language": 200, "Code": "Test", "token": "abcd123412341234","serialNo": "20161020160455982841" }` ?

Comment: change the return type of `authorize` and test it again just for test.

Comment: @Aria sorry , what you mean by change the type of authorize ?

Comment: You are welcome, your `authorize ` method will return `Stream` data, change your method to return string data instead of `Stream` and test it.

Comment: @Aria I had try your suggestion , its still cant access to my service. If i left my strJSONToSend be empty , it can access does that mean something wrong with my JSON data ? but the same coding i can access to my customer web service. Got no idea , is there any setting need to done in Web.config or wat ...

Comment: okay, I think you have to send `strJSONToSend` as a stream not JSON string or change `BodyStyle` to `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare`, try this and let me know what is the result.

Comment: @Aria i had try the change `BodyStyle` to `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` still no luck with that. Possible Web.config issue ?

Comment: Did you pass your JSON as stream if this not the solution, should to redesign `web.config`.

Comment: @Aria thanks for giving so much patient, im new to C# too, how to change the JSON as stream ? And im thinking to redesign the `web.config` but the  coding that i posted were the simple one already. No idea with that really ...

Comment: You are wlc , don't worry it will be resolved finally, to make `Stream` from your string JSON  by C# `var jsonStream=  new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strJSONToSend ));`

Comment: @Aria i have updated the server log , any idea for this ?

Comment: Remove the Namespace from your DataContract  like `[DataContract(Namespace="")]`

Comment: @Aria same error also. Is that anything related to WebContentTypeMapper  ? Because the server log mention about that .

Comment: yes, should be forced to return `Raw` always should use custom `WebContentTypeMapper` take a look at  [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web-receiving-arbitrary-data/)

Comment: @Aria is that possible to set something like that at Web.config ?

Comment: As you set `BodyStyle` to `Wrapped` you JSON data should be something like `{ "streamdata": { "acctid": "123"} };`, but for `WebContentTypeMapper ` you should custom it and change the config little a bit.

Comment: @H.Kai Did you resolved the prob ?

Comment: @Aria Yes i solve it already by adding custom WebContentTypeMapper, thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question my adding the custom WebContentTypeMapper.
Here are my sample coding :

Create new class to allow receive the data as RAW type

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
namespace SampleArticle
{
    public class MyWebContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
    {
        public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
        {

            return WebContentFormat.Raw;
        }
    }
}
```

Web.Config add custom binding to the service

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="SampleArticle.RestService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="RawReceiveCapable" contract="SampleArticle.IRestService" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>


    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="RawReceiveCapable">
                <webMessageEncoding webContentTypeMapperType="SampleArticle.MyWebContentTypeMapper, SampleArticle, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                <httpTransport manualAddressing="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000" transferMode="Streamed"/>
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This Solved my issue , hope its help other too. Thank for helping

Comment: Good job, as you have seen I said in one of my comments under you question that should be forced to return Raw always so the custom `WebContentTypeMapper` must be implemented.